# event listener not being called

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I resolve my problem?

I load all images and image buttons when I click on a button but after that when I try to click on close button (image4) the event listener cannot listen because everything is set in another function.

```
private function onShop(evt:MouseEvent)
{
        shop.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onShop);

        var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var ibutton:Sprite = new Sprite();
        addChild(container);
        addChild(ibutton);
        ibutton.buttonMode = true;

        function loadImage(path:String):Loader
        {
           var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path);
           var loader:Loader = new Loader();
           loader.load(request);
           return loader;
        };

        var image1 = loadImage("image/inventory/shop_windoww.png");
        image1.x = 200;
        image1.y = 40;
        this.addChildAt(image1,8);
        var image2 = loadImage("image/inventory/title_window.png");
        image2.x = 200;
        image2.y = 14;
        container.addChild(image2);
        var image3 = loadImage("image/inventory/icon_window.png");
        image3.x = 177;
        image3.y = 7;
        container.addChild(image3);     
        var image4 = loadImage("image/inventory/close.png");
        image4.x = 891;
        image4.y = 39;
        ibutton.addChild(image4);       
        var image5 = loadImage("image/inventory/button_ok.png");
        image5.x = 450;
        image5.y = 485;
        ibutton.addChild(image5);       
        var image6 = loadImage("image/inventory/button_ok.png");
        image6.x = 782;
        image6.y = 485;
        ibutton.addChild(image6);       

        image4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);

    }

    private function test(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        image4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);
        trace("ca marche");
    }
```

Comment: and i dont wanna declare and load my picture at top of the document

Comment: Could you  share the whole class source? And share the error also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables outside of the onShop scope. They seem to have more sense as global variables, not only local (because you are trying to use the same variables declared on the onShop method on test method).

I also recommend you some points:

- Use an external file (JSON/XML) to get all image URLs, or just use a simple Array with hardcoded content;
- Use a `for` loop to load all images (after following the previous suggestion);
- Use [event.currentTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) in your test method, so, you can deal with those images with a more generic way.

*[event.currentTarget] The object that is actively processing the Event object with an event listener. For example, if a user clicks an OK button, the current target could be the node containing that button or one of its ancestors that has registered an event listener for that event.*

Comment: if i wanted this methode its because i have 10 window (domodal) to open so if i declare my variable global i have to declare 10 different variable (one of each window) and about the loop yes i know a loop is the best but i dont know how to do for resolving my problem because one image need to be resized and if i use a loop i'll resize every image

Comment: ok thanks i just figure out how i can solve my problem using xml and loop :) if i use "if" in the loop i'll be able to control the resize image hehe thanks again for your tips

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I meant, it's not just because you are using a loop, that you cannot have conditionals! Glad for helping!